# General question about differential forms

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Okay so I am extremely new to Diff Geo. I was wondering about differential forms, which from my understanding is the $dx$ portion of an integral and is independent of choice of coordinate chart. Does this mean that no matter which variable becomes your chart, you get the same answer ? So then from basic elementary calculus, is this the reason why when you do disk or washer method and integrate along $x$ or $y$ as the spinning axis you get different results? If one were to use forms instead would you yield same answer? OR am I not correct in even comparing these two? Sorry just want a better handle of what independent of choice of coordinate means. Also does its dimension have anything to do with ambient space or rather if we are finding length area or volume? So a $2$ forms does surface area ad $3$ form does volumes or

Comment: $dx$ is the **derivative** of the projector $x(a,b)=a$ and $dy$ is for the other projector $y(a,b)=b$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: by projector do you mean chart?

Comment: the functions $x$ and $y$ project onto the axes and they are linear, their derivatives are $dx$ and $dy$.